# Conda command not responding

Tags: python, conda

I ran `conda update --all`, then all my env are unavailable to activate.

And the Conda command is not responding, it is not "not found".

Have anyone experienced this before?

I'm considering remove and reinstall everything if I can't find any solution.

[image: Terminal Screenshot]

[image]

[image]

`which __conda_exe` and `echo "$CONDA_EXE"`

[image]

Comment: make sure you are in the base environment. conda activate

Comment: Okay, continuing debugging... add output from `which __conda_exe` and `echo "$CONDA_EXE"`. Basically, let's identify where it is failing. Does `/Users/bryce/miniforge3/condabin/conda info` work?

Comment: @merv Added, it output ```zsh: killed``` when running ```/Users/bryce/miniforge3/condabin/conda info```.

Comment: Then sounds like an architecture issue. This is M1, so did you install the **osx-arm64** build of Miniforge?

Comment: @merv Yes I did, it worked fine before I updated ```numpy```. I have solved the problem by removing the ```/miniforge3``` directory, and reinstall it and its package again. And I'm not sure if the Python version has something to do with it, I was using ```Python 3.10.2```. Now ```Python 3.9.10``` works perfectly.